# Email notification through SNS and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I am facing an issue. My main motive is to send an email whenever there is state change happened to ec2 instances.

I tried cloud watch events directly with SNS and its work also but the email template which I am receiving is not having the proper information to understood.

I was expecting Server name and its IP in the email template which SNS does not give me the option to modify it. So What I am thinking is to involve lambda so that

- cloudwatch events to monitor EC2 instances state change and
- give input to Lambda which will have customized email template which is
- then invoke SNS to send email to recipients.

Let me know if you think this is correct method for what I am expecting or not. and give some insights on how to get Lambda in between Cloud watch and SNS

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 6):

As shown in the **Amazon CloudWatch Events** console, a sample event triggered by an instance state change is:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "7bf73129-1428-4cd3-a780-95db273d1602",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2015-11-11T21:29:54Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-abcd1111"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": "i-abcd1111",
    "state": "pending"
  }
}
```

CloudWatch events can then **directly trigger an AWS Lambda function**, passing in this information.

The Lambda function can use the Instance ID to **retrieve further details** about the instance (eg server name, IP address).

The function can then either:

- Send text to an **Amazon SNS Topic**, which can forward the information to subscribers (via email or SMS), *OR*
- Send the emails via **Amazon Simple Email Service (SES)**, which can send emails with complex formatting

Using **SNS would be the easiest**, if you don't mind the text-based content.

Here is some sample code that will **receive an event from Amazon CloudWatch Events** when an instance changes state, then **send a message to an Amazon SNS topic** with further details:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Extract Instance ID from event
    instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']

    # Obtain information about the instance
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    instance_info = ec2_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    instance = instance_info['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]

    # Extract name tag
    name_tags = [t['Value'] for t in instance['Tags'] if t['Key']=='Name']
    name = name_tags[0] if name_tags is not None else ''

    # Send message to SNS
    MY_SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:foo'
    sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
    sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn = MY_SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        Subject = 'Instance Change State: ' + instance_id,
        Message = 'Instance: ' + instance_id + ' has changed state\n' +
                  'State: ' + instance['State']['Name'] + '\n' +
                  'IP Address: ' + instance['PublicIpAddress'] + '\n' +
                  'Name: ' + name
    )
```

To setup:

- Create an SNS topic to receive the message and put the topic ARN in the code
- Create a subscriber to the SNS topic (easiest is via SMS when testing)
- Create the AWS Lambda function (shown above)
- Create an Amazon CloudWatch Event to trigger off EC2 instance state change, and set the target to the Lambda function

Comment: Thank you @John for your directions. as I am not a coder and finding it difficult to write it down some lambda functions for this purpose. can you please help to get one such functions or any link which you saw having the same methodology so that I can use and tweak it accordingly. that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @John, I will try this code. one more thing I would like to clarify. The lambda function will need IAM permission to send data to SNS and to fetch data from cloudwatch ?
Thanks & Regards

Comment: It will only need permission for EC2 `describe_instances` and SNS `publish`. The information from CloudWatch is automatically sent when the Lambda function is invoked, so it does not need to call CloudWatch.

Comment: Thank you @John for your help and inputs, your code worked for me :) your lambda code did 80% of my work. can you please suggest how can I master lambda functions, any link, pdf online which I can refer to learn.
Thanks & Regards

Comment: It's just normal code written in Python, C#, node that uses the AWS SDK, with an event as input. It really just comes down to looking in the documentation for an AWS function that does what you want, then trying to interpret the response that comes back.

Comment: Got you @John Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

A sample code is shown below. This will really be helpful for you.

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
#print(event)
test={}
test['instanceID']=event['detail']['configuration']['metrics'][0]['metricStat']['metric']['dimensions']['InstanceId']
test['CPUALARM']='The CPU of the'+ test['instanceID']+'has gone above 80%'
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
instance_info = ec2_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[str(test['instanceID'])])
print(instance_info)
sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
response=sns_client.publish(
TopicArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1234567890:test',
Subject = 'CPU-ALARM: ' + test['instanceID'],
Message = str(test)
)
print(response)
return {
'statusCode': 200,
'body': test
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer