# Lamda function to get instance tag and publish to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda function to get instance id from cloudwatch of a newly launched aws instance and check for group of tag and if tag is not there, publish to a sns topic, but i am getting below error

> Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': unexpected indent (lambda_function.py, line 5)

Here is my updated lambda function

```
import boto3
SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxx:xxxx'
CODES = ['ttl', 'GGG', 'BRB', 'YLO']
def lambda_handler(event, context):
user = record['userIdentity']['userName']
        region = record['awsRegion']
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name = 'ap-south-1')
    # Extract Instance ID from event
    instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']
    instance_object = ec2.Instance(instance['instanceId'])
    try:
        tags = {}
        for tag in instance_object.tags:
            tags[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']
        if('Code' not in tags or tags['Code'] not in CODES):
            sns.publish(TopicArn=SNS_TOPIC_ARN, Message=report(instance, user, region))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Comment: This is _very_ similar to: [Email notification through SNS and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52195331/174777)

Comment: Thanks i will look into this and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a `try` statement:

```
import boto3
SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxx:xxxx'
CODES = ['ttl', 'GGG', 'BRB', 'YLO']
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Extract Instance ID from event
    instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']
    instance_object = ec2.Instance(instance['instanceId'])
    try:
        tags = {}
        for tag in instance_object.tags:
            tags[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']
        if('Code' not in tags or tags['Code'] not in CODES):
            sns.publish(TopicArn=SNS_TOPIC_ARN, Message=report(instance, user, region))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error 'detail': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']
KeyError: 'detail'

Comment: The 'shape' of the event dictionary coming from CloudWatch Events isn't what you think it is (or maybe you're testing the function with a different input).  Try adding a `print(event)` statement at the top to see what the input looks like.

Comment: It is correct, Now i am stuck at some other phase i have updated the answer.

Comment: your indentation is inconsistent.  I suspect you're mixing spaces and tabs in your whitespace, a difference which only becomes visible when you copy code from one place to another.  In general, python recommends using spaces rather than tabs for indentation.