# Is there any way to trigger code inside EC2 from Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

Requirement:

1. Sending mail via SMTP(only via SMTP for specific reason) to the user which is read through event "RunInstances" from cloud-trail.
2. As SMTP code is not working with lambda I will have to kept inside EC2 and trigger it through lambda.

Comment: What is your specific issue with having the Lambda function reach your SMTP server? Have you tried connecting the Lambda function to the same VPC as the SMTP server?

Comment: FYI: Your earlier, identical, Question was closed as "too broad", which indicates that you did not supply enough information for people to be able to offer advice. Rather than creating another identical question, it would be a good idea for you to improve the level of detail in your question. It will make it more likely that you receive a relevant response.

Comment: Yes,I tried SMTP in lambda it is not working and I can't use SES also as all the mail must be verified in SES.

Comment: You can configure an HTTP endpoint on EC2 which lambda can trigger , a GET or POST request on that HTTP endpoint can trigger your smtp services.

Comment: @JamesDean can you please a sample snippet how can I do that by configuring endpoint on EC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options:

1. Use SQS: Use Lambda to send messages to SQS, add workers in your EC2s to consume the messages.
2. Create a server in EC2 that listens to traffic from a port, for example: 80. Use Lambda to send HTTP requests to the EC2 server.
3. (Not recommended for this case): Use Step Function Activity. Lambda to call step function, passes the input which is email content. The step function will run and create an activity. The EC2 instance will then have a worker implemented that keep polling activities from the Step function.

Comment: Thanks, but the solution seems to be complected and lengthy is there is other solution to send mail using SMTP.

Comment: then use the Solution #3 :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be that you have an AWS Lambda function that will send an email to various people whenever an instance has been created. However, your Lambda function is unable to reach your SMTP server.

Rather than creating a complex workaround using Amazon EC2, I would recommend that you use **Amazon SES** as an SMTP server to send the emails.

I would also recommend that you use **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to trigger the AWS Lambda function rather than looking for `RunInstances` in a CloudTrail trail.

For an example, see: [Email notification through SNS and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52195331/174777)

Comment: Well, If I use the SES then each and every mail must be verified but if the user mail who created the instance is not verified in SES then SES will throw the error that mail is not verified in SES.

Comment: Amazon SES only requires email addresses to be verified while operating in sandbox mode. See: [Moving Out of the Amazon SES Sandbox - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)

Comment: As I am doing in prod environment so, it is not good practice to move account out of sandbox.

Comment: If I use SNS in this case the details of the user who created the ec2 instance is not coming in JSON formatted event.

Comment: It is not moving an "account out of sandbox". Amazon SES by default works in a "sandbox mode" until you specifically request a change. It only affects SES, not your whole AWS account.

Comment: I will try to take a permission to do so but if I follow it then email or domain need not to be verified in SES or anything else procedure to be done to send mail to not verified mails.