# aws s3 events sns topic notification mail human readable format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want s3 events with sns but I want email notification user-readable in the sense of only I to want time stamps, objects put only. we need only human-readable.

Answer (score 0):

S3 trigger lambda, lambda send email to user via SNS

Comment: To illustrate: The sample code on [Email notification through SNS and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52195331/174777) shows how to put specific content in the Amazon SNS message.

Answer (score 0):

S3 by default send complete JSON as an event, you have two option to send human-readable formate email.

- Configure cloud watch trail with cloud watch event and transform the input with object and time stamp only and set destination SNS

You can look into [CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Input-Transformer-Tutorial.html) and [Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

- the second approach is simple and easy as suggested, configure lambda grab required property and publish to SNS, subscribe email to SNS topic now the message will be the human-readable format.

  - Add notification on s3 with put event only and send to lambda
    [image]
  - Create a lambda function and  assign the role to publish to SNS topic

role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "sns-permission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:YOUR_ACCOUNT:demo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Lambda function example

```
'use strict';

// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');


const sns = new AWS.SNS()

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var eventTime= event.Records[0].eventTime;      
  const params = {
    Message: "bucket:" + bucket + "Object Name:  "+key+ " Event Time:" + eventTime,
    Subject: 'Test SNS From Lambda',
    TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789:demo'
  };

  let response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('SNS message'),
  };
  try {
    const data = await sns.publish(params).promise();
    response.messageId = data.MessageId,
    response.result = 'Success'
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.stack)
    response.result = 'Error'
  }
  return response

};
```

In this case the email will only contain

```
bucket:mybucketObject Name:  HappyFace.jpg Event Time:1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```