# EC2 instance state change alerts Lambda , Cloud Event & SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want that if state of my ec2 will change then I will receive a SNS and it contains ec2 name ,instance id and account name, region.

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Extract Instance ID from event
    instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']

    # Obtain information about the instance
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    instance_info = ec2_client.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    instance = instance_info['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]

    # Extract name tag
    name_tags = [t['Value'] for t in instance['Tags'] if t['Key']=='Name']
    name = name_tags[0] if name_tags is not None else ''

    # Send message to SNS
    MY_SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:foo'
    sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
    sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn = MY_SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        Subject = 'Instance Change State: ' + instance_id,
        Message = 'Instance: ' + instance_id + ' has changed state\n' +
                  'State: ' + instance['State']['Name'] + '\n' +
                  'IP Address: ' + instance['PublicIpAddress'] + '\n' +
                  'Name: ' + name
    )
```

Getting below error...

START RequestId: 7c29aec4-2d51-4b29-91a0-8fc1217397ce Version: $LATEST
'detail': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 6, in lambda_handler
instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']
KeyError: 'detail'

Comment: How are you invoking the function? Did you create the CloudWatch Event as per [Email notification through SNS and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52195331/174777)? It would appear that the function is not receiving event information from CloudWatch Events.

Comment: Can you add `print(event)` at the beginning of your function handler and check the event object structure?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the trigger by cloudwatch event and create cloudwatch event based on EC2 instance state-change?

At first glance, the event pattern preview is

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ]
}
```

So please check with above and give us more information about your case.

Comment: Yes, But it didn't give  EC2 name. I want Ec2 name.

Comment: Can you print the event out so that we can check if we need to customize the userdata or not?