# Get AWS Inspector findings report from AWS Inspector in mail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I want to get the AWS Inspector assessment run findings on email.

For that i had configured a **SNS topic** but the mail i received contains arns(refer pic) :
[image]

The **json data** is non-readable(from pic):

{

"template":"arn:aws:inspector:eu-central-1::target/0-nuQpXxdr/template/0-ZgdD12jw",

"run":"arn:aws:inspector:eu-central-1::target/0-nuQpXxdr/template/0-ZgdD12jw/run/0-xNByk8Qd",

"time":"2022-01-19T12:24:51.348Z",

"finding":"arn:aws:inspector:eu-central-1::target/0-nuQpXxdr/template/0-ZgdD12jw/run/0-xNByk8Qd/finding/0-ZGYFvyQi",

"event":"FINDING_REPORTED",

"target":"arn:aws:inspector:eu-central-1::target/0-nuQpXxdr"

}

**REQUIRED:** I need a way to get the ***whole report(pdf/html) or URL*** of this report and not singular un-readable finding. Is there any way out to do so??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For AWS Inspector Classic:**
One way I would do it is by having 2 SNS topics let's call them sns1 and sns2, where sns1 has a lambda function subscribed to it, and sns2 sends emails as notifications.

The lambda function here will receive the JSON, convert it into a readable format and push it sns2.

**For AWS Inspector V2** you can get rid of the sns1 topic and replace it with AWS EventBridge for lambda.

Here are some links to help you:

- [How do I subscribe a Lambda function to an Amazon SNS topic in the same account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-subscribe-sns-topic-same-account/)
- [How to Remediate Amazon Inspector Security Findings Automatically](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-remediate-amazon-inspector-security-findings-automatically/)
- [Email notification through SNS and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194888/email-notification-through-sns-and-lambda)

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use the AWS Security hub.

How to set up a recurring Security Hub summary email - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-a-recurring-security-hub-summary-email/

The above link guides you through a process that helps you get an email of inspector reports.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31610249)