# Receiving error while running python code in Lambda to send email with attachment from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-3.9

I am newbie with Python and AWS..My use case is to share the file that is in specific s3 bucket with the recipients on daily basis.

To achieve this use case, I tried to use the following code in lambda function and test it from code source. Unfortunately, I am running into issue where the details that are being fetched from event['Records'] does not map to the bucket details that I am looking for. Can someone please help me in identifying where the issue is?

```
import os.path
import boto3
import email
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication


s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    SENDER = 'sender'
    RECIPIENT = 'receiver'
    AWS_REGION = 'aws region'
    SUBJECT = 'Test'
    FILEOBJ = event['Records'][0]
    BUCKET_NAME = str(FILEOBJ['s3']['bucket']['name'])
    KEY = str(FILEOBJ['s3']['object']['key'])
    FILE_NAME = os.path.basename(BUCKET_NAME) 

    print(event['Records'])

    BODY_TEXT = "Hello,\r\nPlease see the attached report."
    # The HTML body of the email.
    BODY_HTML = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <p>Please see the attached report.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    CHARSET = 'utf-8'

    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT 
    msg['From'] = SENDER 
    msg['To'] = RECIPIENT
    msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
    htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)
    msg_body.attach(textpart)
    msg_body.attach(htmlpart)
    msg.attach(msg_body)

    try:
        response = client.send_raw_email(
            Source=SENDER,
            Destinations=[
                RECIPIENT
            ],
            RawMessage={
                'Data':msg.as_string(),
            },
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print("Email sent! Message ID:")
        print(response['MessageId'])
```

Tried to test the actual details that are being called from event['Records'][0] and noticed that the bucket information that we are targeting is not included and so receiving error response as below:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Comment: Try to use SNS to send emails instead of directly sending email from Lambda, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194888/email-notification-through-sns-and-lambda

Comment: `HeadObject` is a S3 permission.  Your user doesn't have permission to read from S3.